# How to separate schemas, methods and statics in different files in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to improve the file structure of my Nodejs code with Mongoose.

I've already separated each Schemas in different files, but for some schemas the number of methods and statics are pretty large, and I'm ending up with schema files that are too big (>1500 lines).

I wanted to separate the methods and schemas in different files and "require" them in the schema

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  pwdhash: String,
});

UserSchema.methods.someMethod1 = function() {
  // Do something 1
};

UserSchema.methods.someMethod2 = function() {
  // Do something 2
};

var User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

I wanted it to look like this:

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  pwdhash: String,
});

// Requiring methods
require("./methods/user.js");

var User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

However, on the /methods/user.js file I can't find out how to retrieve the Schema (only the Model) from the mongoose instance to assign the methods.

Am I missing something? Is there some better alternative for separating methods and statics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

make a methods.js file, and in methods file add this code:

```
module.exports = function(UserSchema) {
    UserSchema.methods.someMethod1 = function() {
    // Do something 1
    };

    UserSchema.methods.someMethod2 = function() {
    // Do something 2
    };
}
```

after that in your main file, you have to do this:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  pwdhash: String,
});

// Requiring methods
require("./methods.js")(UserSchema);

var User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

I'm pretty sure this will work :)

Comment: Excellent! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

This is one way of doing it.

UserMethods.js

```
module.exports = {
 someMethod1: function() {...};
 someMethod2: function() {...};
}
```

User.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  pwdhash: String,
});

Object.assign(UserSchema.methods, require("./UserMethods.js"));

var User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the first thing I'll say is that if you have 1500+ lines in a schema file, there's a good chance that you're putting too much stuff into the model logic rather than making use of modules that hold functionality that you can then wire together in your model.

That said, the most mongoosy way to do this is actually to make use of their plugins architecture.  This is a great way to get reuse as well as to separate.

Let's say you want to add a `findByName` method as a static to all schemas, since many schemas might have a 'name' attribute.  You can define this:

```
// ./plugins/find-by-name.js
function findByName(name, callback) {
  this.find({ name: new RegExp(name, 'i') }, callback);
}

function findByNamePlugin(schema, options) {
  schema.statics.findByName = findByname;
}

module.exports = findByNamePlugin;
```

Then in your UserSchema file you can just require and add them.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var findByNamePlugin = require('./plugins/findByName');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  pwdhash: String,
});
UserSchema.plugin(findByNamePlugin);
// add others.
```